# jQuery Tabs Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have some jquery tabs working

http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/e8rfqw8g/

But what I cant work out is if someone clicks on a tab the title changes which is outside the tab content

This is what I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'), $ct = $(this).closest('.tab-ct');

    $ct.find('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current');
    $ct.find('.tab-content.current').removeClass('current');
    $ct.find('.tab-title.current').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
});

});
```

The HTML is

```
<div class="tab-ct">
  <h2 id="tab1" class="tab-title current">Tab 1</h2>
  <h2 id="tab2" class="tab-title">Tab 2</h2>
  <h2 id="tab3" class="tab-title">Tab 3</h2>

  <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab1">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  </ul>

<div id="tab1" class="tab-content current">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus metus mauris, sed lacinia ipsum ullamcorper interdum. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam.
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus metus mauris, sed lacinia ipsum ullamcorper interdum. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam.
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus metus mauris, sed lacinia ipsum ullamcorper interdum. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam.
</div>

</div>
```

The title changes ok but now the tab content doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the ID's i'm not sure

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ID of an element must be unique**.

When you use an id-selector, it will return only the first element with the given id, in your case both the `h2` and `.tab-content` has the same id so it is returning only the `h2` as it is first in the dom structure.

One possible solution in this case is to use a prefix/suffix to one of those ids. In the below solution a suffix `-title` is added to the `h2`

```
<div class="tab-ct">
     <h2 id="next-game-title" class="tab-title current">Tab 1</h2>
     <h2 id="table-title" class="tab-title">Tab 2</h2>
     <h2 id="last-game-title" class="tab-title">Tab 3</h2>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="next-game">17/01/15 - 15:00</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="table">Table</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="last-game">Last Game</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="next-game" class="tab-content current">Content 1</div>
    <div id="table" class="tab-content">Content 2</div>
    <div id="last-game" class="tab-content">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
            $ct = $(this).closest('.tab-ct');

        $ct.find('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current');
        $ct.find('.tab-content.current').removeClass('current');
        $ct.find('.tab-title.current').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id + '-title').addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x1ea5nv1/)